# How to use the names from original graph on quotient graph?

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph

I have a graph `g1` and I need to find the [quotient graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_graph) `g2`.
My attept is:

```
library(igraph)

n = 8
m <- t(matrix(c(
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,
3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
5,0,0,5,1,0,0,0,
0,0,6,0,0,7,1,0,
0,6,2,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
7,4,0,0,8,0,0,3,
0,3,0,0,0,9,0,0),ncol=n))

g1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m, weighted=TRUE, mode="directed")
V(g1)$names <- letters[1:n]
V(g1)$label <- V(g1)$names

g2 <- contract(g1, components(g1, mode = "strong")$membership, vertex.attr.comb=toString)
g2 <- simplify(g2)
```

The graph `g2` has three componets:  {a, b, h}, {c, d, e, g} and {f} and I need to use the first letters from each component as vertex.labels.

```
plot(g2, vertex.label = substr(toupper(V(g2)$label), 1, 1))
```

The result is correct for me:

[image]

**Question.** Is it possible to solve the task without using the additional attribute  V(g1)$label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$name` (instead of `$names`) to add vertex name attribute, e.g.,

```
g1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m, weighted = TRUE, mode = "directed")
V(g1)$name <- letters[1:n]

g2 <- contract(g1, components(g1, mode = "strong")$membership, vertex.attr.comb = toString)
g2 <- simplify(g2)
```

then, when you run `plot(g2)`, you will see

[image]